# TSQL- stored procedure dynamically handle varying number of parameters to execute stored procedure per parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grafana

I am working on a grafana dashboard that will allow be to select one or more server and port combination to return data PER server+port combination.

```
DECLARE
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME,
    @ServerId SMALLINT,  

SET @StartDate =  DATEADD(HH,-1, @StartDate) 
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
SET @ServerId = (SELECT ServerId FROM dbo.Server 
                 WHERE ServerName = [[ServerName]] AND ServerPort = [[ServerPort]])

EXECUTE GetGrafana  @StartDate ,  @EndDate, @ServerId, 18 //Ignore the 18, not relevant to this question
```

In Grafana, "[[ServerName]]" and "[[ServerPort]] " dynamically changes as I click on different combination so [[ServerName]] and [[ServerPort]]. So the actual query could look like this:

```
SET @ServerId = (SELECT ServerId FROM dbo.Server 
                 WHERE ServerName = 's001','s002','s003' AND ServerPort = '1111','2222','3333','4444')
```

If I select just one "[[ServerName]]" and "[[ServerPort]] " combination, it can execute the stored procedure. But it errors when I try to put multiple combinations because `ServerId` can't have multiple ServerName and ServerPort . I'm wondering how I can configure my query to be allow me to handle multiple "[[ServerName]]" and "[[ServerPort]] " in ServerID and call the stored procedure per `ServerID`.

Comment: Consider: Comma-separated list parameters and `string_split` function

Comment: You should show us how the `GetGrafana` is implemented - so that we can modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. create a function that would split your string based on a specific delimiter (seems like in this case the delimiter would be a comma
2. use that function to split your string of server names

   ```
   create function [dbo].[split_str]
   (
       @parameter nvarchar(max), 
       @delimiter char(1)
   )
   returns @res table (val nvarchar(max), seq int)
   as
   begin

   set @parameter += @delimiter

   ;with cte as
   (
       select cast(1 as bigint) f, charindex(@delimiter, @parameter) t, 1 seq
       union all
       select t + 1, charindex(@delimiter, @parameter, t + 1), seq + 1
       from cte
       where charindex(@delimiter, @parameter, t + 1) > 0
   )
   insert @res
   select substring(@parameter, f, t - f), seq 
   from cte
   option (maxrecursion 0)
   ```

   return
   end

And then, in your `GetGrafana` procedure instead of having a `where` clause with `=`, have one with `IN` as below:

```
where ServerName IN dbo.split_str(ServerName, ',')
```

As of SQL Server 2016 you can make use of the built-in [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.